# Kotlin sortBy on TreeMap

Tags: group-by, treemap, kotlin

What is the kotlin way of accomplisg this:

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<HomeItem>> getHomeItemListsSeparatedByPageId(List<HomeItem> homeItemsList) {

        if (homeItemsList.size() == 0) {
            return new TreeMap<>();
        }

        TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<HomeItem>> map = new TreeMap<>();

        for (HomeItem hl : homeItemsList) {
            if (map.get(hl.getVisiblePageId()) == null) {
                map.put(hl.getVisiblePageId(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            map.get(hl.getVisiblePageId()).add(hl);
        }

        return map;
    }
```

I have tried to apply groupBy on my args list but it returns an HashMap.

EDIT: Basically, the original list is queried, and it is grouped by `visiblePageId`, and added to a treemap whose key is the id and the value are the items with that id

Comment: In questions you should show what you tried in Kotlin, that you made an attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [groupByTo method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/kotlin.-iterable/group-by-to.html) and pass a `TreeMap` instance as the first argument.

```
fun getHomeItemListsSeparatedByPageId(homeItems: List<HomeItem>) =
    homeItems.groupByTo(TreeMap()) { it.visiblePageId }
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? I might be missing something but I can't get that to work without using an unchecked cast: `listOf<HomeItem>().groupByTo(TreeMap<Int, ArrayList<HomeItem>>() as MutableMap<Int, MutableList<HomeItem>>) { it.visiblePageId }`.

Should not `groupByTo` take `map: MutableMap<K, out MutableList<T>>` instead of `map: MutableMap<K, MutableList<T>>`?

Comment: @mfulton26 Edited answer to include example. The compiler is smart enough to infer the types; you don't need to use any type arguments at all.

Comment: Whoa! That is awesome! I had no idea you could do that in Kotlin. And you can cast it `as TreeMap` without the types and it casts it to `TreeMap<Int, MutableList<HomeItem>>`. Wonderful! Thank you @yole!